# .error() em jQuery is not a funciton

Tags: jquery

Inseri após o carregamento de todo o conteúdo de meu website a função abaixo, e está retornando uma mensagem de erro no console.

> TypeError: $(...).error is not a function

Tentei corrigir isso usando o [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mas o erro persiste.

Estou usando a versão 3.3.1 do jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
       var $images = $('img.imageClassUpdateAtInterval:not([src="/assets/images/ico-loading.gif"])');

      // Now, no such image with
       // a spinner
       if($images.length === 0 && window.imageLocator)
         clearInterval(window.imageLocator);


        window.imageLocator = setInterval(function() {
            $images.each(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                if (!$this.data('src')) {
                    $this.data('src', $this.prop('src'));
                }

                $this.prop('src', $this.data('src') + '?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime());
                console.log($this.prop('src'));
            });
        }, 60 * 8000);

       // suppose, an error occured during
       // locating the src (source) of the
       // image - image not found, network
       // unable to locate the resource etc.
       // it will fall in each time on error
       // occurred 
       $('img.imageClassUpdateAtInterval').error(function () {   
                 // set a broken image
                 $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "/assets/images/ico-loading.gif"); 
                 // setting this up in relative
                 // position
                 $(this).css("position", "relative");
                 $(this).apppend("<span><!--error--></span>");
                 $(this).find("span").css({"position": "absolute", "background-color": "#252525", "padding": ".3em", "bottom": "0"});
       });

    });
})
```

Comment: Você já verificou se a referência para o jquery é carregada antes da execução deste script?

Comment: @SérgioLopes é sim, a função executa após o load do arquivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação oficial](https://api.jquery.com/error/), o evento `.error()` foi considerado obsoleto a partir da versão 1.8 e **removido** a partir da versão 3.0 do jQuery.

Em vez disso, use:

```
$('img.imageClassUpdateAtInterval').on("error", function(){
   // códigos
});
```

para disparar o evento `error`.

Não há necessidade de usar `.noConflict()`.

> **Dica:** já que está usando uma versão bem recente do jQuery, fique ligado que muitas funções e métodos do jQuery mais antigo foram
>   removidos a partir da versão 3.0, como, por exemplo, esse `.unbind()`
>   que está usando, que foi substituído por `.off()` ([veja aqui](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)). Quando se deparar com um erro, consulte a documentação para ver o que foi alterado.

Comment: Obrigado pela paciência @Sam